# Antlr4 doesn't find any viable alternative for an input string on a simple grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I'm a newbie in Antlr and I have to create some grammar to parse rules and formulas which specified by users in my project. I've been written the hardest one that contain conditional statement already, but for the second one that is so easier than the first one, I get no viable alternative for the input.
My grammar is a simple grammar which demonstrated below:

```
grammar PmntIdntfrTmpExp;

start
    :   statement 
    |   statement start
    ;

statement
    :   assignment
    ;

assignment
    :   id '=' addStmt
    ;

addStmt
    :   addStmt '+' mulStmt
    |   addStmt '-' mulStmt
    |   mulStmt
    ;


mulStmt
    :   mulStmt '*' terminal
    |   mulStmt '/' terminal
    |   mulStmt '^' terminal
    |   terminal
    ;

terminal
    :   '('addStmt')'
    |   id
    |   number
    ;

id
    :   '@fild'(Digit)+
    ;

number
    :   Digit+ ('.' Digit+)?
    ;

Digit
    :   '0'..'9'
    ;

WS  
    :   [ \t\r\n]+  ->  skip 
    ;
```

But when I wanted to parse even a simple string like the assignment below

```
@fild76 = @fild12 + @fild43
```

I came up with this error

```
line 1:27 no viable alternative at input '@fild76=@fild12+@fild43'
```

### I'll be wonder if any body help me with this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know why your grammar fails, but it seems to be the first rule that breaks it:

Replacing:

```
start
  :   statement 
  |   statement start
  ;
```

with the syntactically equivalent

```
start
  :   statement+
  ;
```

does not emit the error